# How do people keep killing me so fast?

Tags: nuclear-dawn

I keep getting killed within seconds of contact.  Example:

x=wall m=me e=enemy

```
x m   x
x     x
x     xxxxxxxx
x            e
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

x     x
x m   x
x     xxxxxxxx
x            e
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

x     x
x     x
x m   xxxxxxxx
x            e
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

x     x
x     x
x     xxxxxxxx
x  m         e
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And I'm dead nearly instantly.  At first I blamed lag, but this is happening consistently in all kinds of situations. Contact is made, and BAM.  I'm dead.

I've also considered camping, but the game has a minimap so I know where he is just as well as he knows where I am.  In the above example, I had my cursor on where I expected him to be (and he was there) but he killed me faster than I could kill him.  And neither of us were Exo's, so I didn't have to wait for my gun to spin up and he didn't get the advantage of extra firepower.

Is there something I'm missing here or am I just that bad?

Comment: the dude's camping waiting for something to move and then pull the trigger while already aimed at where your head is likely to be

Comment: @ratchet That was just an example. It happens out in the open, also.

Comment: likely a headshot. were you aiming at the body or the head?

Comment: @ratchet I'm not sure...I didn't see him long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What class are you, what class is the opponent?

Support and - even more so - stealth die very quickly especially if the opponent has good aim and manages to hit the head. Support or stealth vs assault is usually very 1-sided unless you manage to suprise the assault by flanking him (though the engineer shotgun can do a ton of damage).

In case of assault vs assault, he might just have better aim and reaction than you.

In short: He was probably just better than you.

Comment: Don't forget the stabilizer adds a dot scope to the assault class. I spectated a guy accused of cheating; turns out he was killing simply because he made effective use of the dot-scope (also note: dot scope for assault doesn't work well if you play with thermal on). Other mods have similarly devastating effects in the hands of good players.

Comment: Personally, i feel like the scope gizmo is bad for assaults in short- to midrange fights. It obscures your vision with thermal enabled and even without thermal (which should be on at all times), the opponent will usually be dead before the scope really comes into effect. The damage and armor penetration mods however can be very effective in the right situations.

Comment: `He was probably just better than you.` The only worse words that can follow that sentence is: `And he's 13 years old`

Comment: @yx I don't know... is it worse getting shot by a 13 year old or your 70 year old grandfather? At least for young people you have the excuse that they are just faster due to age :)

Answer (score 0):

Each individual class has it's own stats, such as the Stealth having 100 health and the Exo having 600. Considering this, some classes also deal more damage than others. The Stealth class with the Sniper kit can kill nearly any enemy in 2 shots, and most classes in 1 shot to the head.

Be sure to note what weapon you were killed with by looking in the top left hand side of the screen, and remember to get healed by Supports or Supply areas.